# Воспроизвести видео с ютуба на форме или где найти компонент Shockwave Flash Player? C#

Tags: c#, winforms, видео

Здравствуйте. Где найти компонент Shockwave Flash Player? В разделе "Компоненты COM", после нажатия правой кнопкой мыши на "Все формы Windows Forms" и выбора пункта "Выбрать элементы..." нужного элемента нет. У меня VS 2015
Или подскажите как можно воспроизвести видео с ютуба без использования webbrowser. Пробовал с помощь WMP, только что-то не получается, он в конечном итоге пишет "Готово", а видео не появляется.

```
  axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"https://youtu.be/rccFLDrWMxc?list=PLj5cSehtnkenCi-bCR55LQyQ74hIbi3Vo";   //указываем путь к видео
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
```

Comment: Походу, в системе должен быть установлен Flash Player, и на форму просто помещаем COM-компонент, управляем им как хотим.

Comment: Adobe Flash Player?

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен в работоспособности (сам не пробовал), но попробуйте это https://wpfyoutubeplayer.codeplex.com

Comment: это для wpf, кажется. У меня просто win-приложение

Comment: @АндрейФедоров: Не бывает «просто win-приложений». Если у вас не приложение командной строки, то вы пользуетесь UI-фреймворком, то есть либо WPF, либо Windows Forms.

Comment: В einforms можно использовать WPF компоненты.